# Dynamics CRM retrieve plug-in is fired multiple times

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I wrote a plug-in for Dynamics CRM 2015 and I want to trigger it every time the user clicks on an account. When I register it with "Update" message, it's fired once. However, when I register with "Retrieve" message, it's fired multiple times. I tried this code below but it didn't work:

```
if (context.Depth > 1)
{
      tracingService.Trace("Depth > 1");
      return;
}
```

I checked the Trace Logs and saw that the plug-in was fired three times in a row (with the same `depth` = 1). If I set the `Excution Mode` from `Sync` to `Async`, the plug-in will be fired 6 times.

Any advice, please?

Edit: This is my plug-in registration

[image]

This is the plug-in was fired three times in Trace Log

[image]

Comment: What is your goal? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to write a plug-in such that whenever the user clicks on an account (to see its details), this plug-in will be triggered to run to insert some kinds of data to the database. So I register this plug-in with Retrieve message. However, when the user clicks on an account, this plug-in is fired three times (hence it inserts the same data three times). I only want this plug-in to run ONCE.

Comment: Can you post an image of the plugin registration?

Comment: Please check the updated post. Thanks!

Comment: is there perhaps code in your plugin that initiates another retrieve for information on that record?  Can you post your whole plugin to confirm that?  or else there could be javascript that runs when the page loads that does a SOAP/OData retrieve on this record.

Comment: Not that this answers why it calls retrieve 3 times, but you could also write a JavaScript onLoad function that does the same thing if you're stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to do some sort of logging when a user tries to view any of the account details: you should write your custom logic in the Form load of the main entity form (or any of the desired forms) of Account.

Internally Retrieve could be used to display many information or to perform different business logic. So triggering your plugin on Retrieve can bring duplicate entries for the same record. Hope this helps.